# Load file from disk in C# - System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core

I'm getting to load my file from disk but I'm getting an error: System.IO.IOException.

```
FileStream attachment;
using (var stream = File.Open(@"c:\testFolder\test.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
 attachment = stream;
}
```

Error from logs:

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.IO.FileSystem.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll 2017-04-20 07:19:08 [Error] Invalid
>   argument

The file exists.

What I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Asp.Net Core 1.1.

Comment: Usually there is an additional information when an exception is thrown. Can you share it too ? ( call `.getMessage()` )

Comment: do you have access to the file, the file is already opened by another application? Show the exception message.

Comment: Which line is throwing Exception? Second line or forth line?

Comment: Off-topic: What you're doing here seems like a very bad idea. You are "leaking" an `IDisposable` out of its `using` block. That is, after the `using` block, `stream` (and therefore `attachment`) will have been disposed and you may no longer use `attachment`.

Comment: are you reading local filesystem in asp.net?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core serving a file outside of the project directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391812/asp-net-core-serving-a-file-outside-of-the-project-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on one of my projects.
I changed the Stream to FileStream:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(yourPath, FileMode.Open))
```

Hope it helps